# Django / JS: Ajax response is not getting message

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, google-chrome-extension

I make an ajax call. It is made from a chrome extension via content_script.js. When completed this should alert the returned message. However, the alert shows the response as being blank.

content_script.js

```
 function got_response(){
     alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
 }

var xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open("POST", domain, true);
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = got_response;
xmlHttp.send();
```

view.py:

```
return HttpResponse("login_error")
```

I get an alert message, but it does not include my message "login_error". I have set breakpoints and it definitely returns from there. It seems that this sometimes works and sometimes doesn't. Like it's a state that it gets into?

Edit: this seems to happen when the request.user is anonymous (also an error because I am logged in)

Comment: The return types on `onreadystatechange` are `xmlhttp.status, xmlhttp.responseText` . Can you change the signature of `got_response` to `got_response(status, responseText)` and `alert(responseText)` ? [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16369406/1628832) should help

Comment: that alerts "undefined"

Comment: can you alert(status)? I have a feeling that the CSRF middleware is blocking your attempt to POST, and you're not doing ANY error handling.

Comment: xmlHttp.readyState = 4, but status in the Network tab is cancelled

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems to be to also add permission to my own site in the manifest file.

```
"permissions": [
    "activeTab",  "http://mysite.com/"
  ],
```